# Laravel: Why is my variable not being set while it's in the construct function of the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, controller

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs,    ValidatesRequests;
    private $host;
    private function __construct()
    {
        $environment = App::environment();
        if ($environment == "local"){
            $this->host = config('customs.localHost');
        }
        else if ($environment == "prod"){
            $this->host = config('customs.productionHost');
        }
    }

    public function getHost()
    {
        return $this->host;
    }
}
```

Above is my controller in the Laravel. This is the main controller, I extend this controller in my other controller classes. Basically I wanted to create a method in this controller which returns the current host according to my current environment.

I'm calling the function getHost() from my other controllers, however I'm getting null.

Now the code in the __construct(), if I put it in the getHost() method it works. However my question here is why doesn't the code in the __construct() get executed?

Comment: Your constructor must be public, or called by the class itself (as in singletons, for example).

Comment: I made it public, however the code is still not being executed.

Comment: Please see this url https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/07-01-2014-extending-basecontroller-when-constructor-has-params

Comment: I think need to pass parameter on constructor method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call

```
parent::__construct();
```

inside the subclass constructor, and the superclass constructor must not be private.

E.g.:

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change visibility of property $host:

```
public $host;
```

and visibility of function __construct:

```
public function __construct()
```

then in your subclass construct function:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Comment: Did you call `parent::__construct();` in your subclass construct function?

Comment: Yes I called parent::__construct(); in my subclass construction and it worked.

Comment: The visibility of the property $host can be changed to private, And function__construct() should be public.

Answer (score 0):

I thought when I'm extending the controller it automatically initializes.

```
class WSUsersController extends Controller
{
}
```

I had to initialize my controller before calling the getHost() method.

```
$controller = New Controller();
$result['campaignRequest'] = $controller->getHost();
```

Comment: Each controller gets initialized when making requests to it, which I think everyone that wrote an answer thought you did (e.g. `get /getHost` and `Route::get('getHost', 'WSUsersController@getHost')`). When calling `getHost` from your code then you do, of course, need to initialize it (if its not a static method)

Comment: So basically when I'm calling the method from the route it gets initialized, and if I'm calling the method from my code (even if I'm extending the class) I need to initialize it by (`parent::__construct()`).

Comment: When calling on a route, the framework will instantiate it for you. What you do need to consider is whether or not `getHost` really is supposed to be in a controller. Maybe Laravel's `ServiceProvider` would do the job!